# how to save user input into registry using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

tried to save user input into windows registry as shown below but
when i run the application, i can't see the new value added into the registry path(which is under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\...

implemented code

```
double myValue = 0.01;
string key = "path";
myValue= value;
Registry.SetValue(key, "my Value", 
               value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
               RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the whole path for the registry key, not just the item relative to HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

So, your code should look something like :

```
const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";    
string key = "path";

Registry.SetValue(userRoot + "\\" + key, "my Value", 
    value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
    RegistryValueKind.String);
```

However, it may be cleaner to use the RegistryKey class as per the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: @user22387 Tried what? The code Martyn posted or the method used on the linked page?

Comment: @itsme86 both, the problem is not with the code as its used with other values and its working, 
the problem with registry itself, why it#s not updating with the new updates?

Comment: @user22387 Are you saying it was working before some Windows updates? This is the first you've mentioned anything about updates.

Comment: @itsme86 not sure what do you mean? i mention the problem is not with the code, its with the registry it self is not adding ( myValue )

Comment: @user22387 What I mean is your "...why it#s not updating with the new updates?" comment. What's the exact key path? Does it have anything to do with WOW64? Is it a 64-bit application? The chances of it being an actual problem with the registry itself are about 0% so you should stop spending your efforts on thinking that's where the problem is.

Comment: Your code is writing the variable value rather than myValue to the registry; is that intentional? Not sure it would make a difference but that comes down to any other code that there may be that's not in your snippet.